# Converting Image To B&W, sepia, GrayScale etc in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage

I was searching on the google if I get something for add effect to the Image like `Black & White`, `Sepia`, `grayScale` etc. I found a useful link for converting Image in `Sepia` but there is nothing for converting it in B&W or Grayscale.

Here is the link http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/b987b02deec08b9f

After going through the code I come to know that we need to change RBG for that but How to get RBG for `B&W` and `grayScale`. What will be the RBG ratio for these kind of effects.

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that is same way as given in the link(google groups).

Also, you can find the logic in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340564/convert-image-to-bw-problem-cgcontext-iphone-dev) to convert them into grayScale.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes this worked very well for Gray scale but for black & White what I want to know is how to calculate RBG colors? As for sepia the link is saying `uint32_t oRed = rgbaPixel[RED] * 0.393 + rgbaPixel[GREEN] * 0.769 + rgbaPixel[BLUE] * 0.189;`
What ratio to use for `B&W` image

Comment: @KapilChoubisa i am facing the same problem please tell me about the ratio to use for B&W image

Answer (score 4):

You can get a B&W Image by

```
-(UIImage *)convertOriginalImageToBWImage:(UIImage *)originalImage
{
UIImage *newImage;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSapce = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, originalImage.size.width * originalImage.scale, originalImage.size.height * originalImage.scale, 8, originalImage.size.width * originalImage.scale, colorSapce, kCGImageAlphaNone);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height), [originalImage CGImage]);

CGImageRef bwImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSapce);

UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bwImage];
CGImageRelease(bwImage);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, NO, originalImage.scale);
[resultImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height)];
newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


return newImage;
}
```