# iPhone iOS how to instantiate a black and white CGColorSpaceRef?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, color-space

I'm working with this excellent example of converting an image to grayscale: [Convert Image to B&W problem CGContext - iPhone Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340564/convert-image-to-bw-problem-cgcontext-iphone-dev)

However, for my purposes, I would like to have **only pure black and pure white** left in the image.

It appears that to do so, I need to pass a black and white color space to the recolor method using a call:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(/*black and white name*/);
```

However, I was unable to find the proper iOS color space names. What I found was from Mac, and the "color space names" referenced from the iOS docs does not point anywhere.

**How can I properly create a black and white CGColorSpaceRef?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with a black and white only color space but what you can do is calculate the total average RGB value from all the pixels (lets call it `totalAvg`) and use it as a threshold. Meaning for each pixel if its rgb average is greater than the calculated `totalAvg` than set it to pure white, otherwise set it to pure black.

I agree it is a bit of more work but thats whay I can think of unless you find the colorspace you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You might try creating a gray color space, then [creating an indexed color space](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorSpaceCreateIndexed) with two colors (black and white, obviously) and using that.