# ImageMagick GrayScale

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, imagemagick

How to convert image to grayscale with ImageMagick in objective-c? I load images to imageMagick and use them as OpenGL textures. I need to make image grayscale on load. I mean make grayscale subImage of original image

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but you can find some logic to convert to Grayscale [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340564/convert-image-to-bw-problem-cgcontext-iphone-dev).

Similar info is available in this [GoogleGroups Posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/iphonesdkdevelopment/uYewLe7Ai58).